How to get $v'=\frac{r}{c}v + \frac{r}{c^2}(1-ke^{cv})$ from $v''-Cv'{}^2+ rv v'=0$?
I had a little trouble when I read the picture below. In (10.4) and (10.5), $c,C,r,k$ are constants. And $v=v(x)$. I try to get (10.5) from (10.4). Integrate (10.4), I have
$$
v'-C\int v'{}^2 + \frac{r}{2} v^2 =0
$$
On the one hand, I don't know how to deal $\int v'{}^2$. On the other hand, it seemly don't like (10.5).




The key idea here is to multiply equation (10.4) by $e^{-cv}$, known as integrating factor, which gives
$$
v'' e^{-cv} - c v'^2 e^{-cv} + r v v' e^{-cv} = 0.
$$
This equation can be written as
$$
(v' e^{-cv})' - \frac{r}{c^2}[(1+cv)e^{-cv}]' = 0.
$$
Integrating this equation gives
$$
v' e^{-cv} - \frac{r}{c^2}(1+cv)e^{-cv} = k'.
$$
where $k'$ is the constant of integration. Setting $k' = kr/c^2$ leads to equation (10.5).

Thank you. Is this the common method of ODE?

Yes. There’s even a Wikipedia article on integrating factor.
